# "No webpage was found for the web addres" error when trying to open swaggerUI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

when trying to open swagger ui page on localhost this error came to me .
I'm working on api that made with asp.net core and I add a lot of methods in startup file and try a lot of solution but without any solving for this problem.

solution to open swagger page[image]

Comment: Hi Abdullah, please show us the swagger related code you're using on your application!

Comment: The URL does not point to Swagger UI in your screenshot. It should be "/swagger"

Comment: a newly created asp.net core api project with .net 6/7 should integrate swagger UI by default and whenever your run the app in visual studio, it should direct to swagger UI automatically becasue we have `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()){app.UseSwagger();app.UseSwaggerUI();}` in `Program.cs`, I'm afraid you can check it and check the `launchsetting.json` had setting `"launchBrowser": true,"launchUrl": "swagger",`

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the URL a second time to make sure it is accurate and full. An mistake can occasionally be caused by a minor typo.
2. If you are certain that the URL is accurate, see if the server hosting the SwaggerUI application is up and operating by checking the server status. 
   You can do this by getting in touch with the server administrator or by using online tools to monitor the server's state.
   3.Delete the cookies in your browser: Then, attempt accessing the URL once more after clearing the cache and cookies in your browser. This can sometimes make the problem go away.
3. Change your browser: If the issue still exists, attempt navigating to the URL using a different browser.